# PC Won't Sustain Power

Tags: cpu, power-supply, troubleshooting, power

I've been using this system almost every day for the past 7 months. It has worked completely fine with no indication of error at all, but now it will not power on. Whether I use the casr button, the button on the mobo, or jumping the pins, it flashes on really quick and then turns off. It's just enough time for my LEDs to flash on and for the fans to rotate a few centimeters. It's not enough time for the mobo to post any error codes, so I can't be sure what's wrong with it. I was building a PC for a friend, and his acted similarly when I tried to jump it after forgetting to plug in the CPU power, so I think that either my 8-pin CPU cable is broken, or my CPU itself. I just wanted to get a second opinion. I have done the standard testing of switching surge protectors, unplugging the power supply and most of my components, and trying everything one by one, although I don't have a replacement CMOS battery so I haven't tried that. I really appreciate anybody who can offer help or advice. Thank you.

System in case anybody might need: 
CPU: 4690k 
GPU: GTX 970
Mobo: Gigabyte G1. Sniper Z97
PSU: Rosewill Lightning 800w

Comment: Is there any way you can get another power supply to test? It sounds like it could be that, or the motherboard. If not, try looking at the steps and info [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/302360-31-computer-turns-split-shuts). Have you tried searching online extensively?

Comment: I don't have any other power supplies in my house, nor functioning motherboards. I have scoured the internet, but most solutions are for new builds and usually involve the system simply not posting. I have also posted on 8 different forums and the only advice I was offered was to get a new PSU because it's "worth a shot." I'm not willing to drop $100+ on a new PSU unless I'm positive it's the problem.

Comment: generally, you cannot troubleshoot without swapping parts,  I see a few $35 PSUs on amazon   or you can try a PSU from your working comp in your friends comp and/or your potentially bad psu(if u wanna go there) in your comp for a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I may as well answer this as I solved it well over a year ago. The issue was actually that two of my fan cables had become pinched underneath a clip inside the case. This caused them to overheat, and their rubber shrouds melted. The exposed wires came in contact and caused a short in the system. Luckily, none of my components were harmed and the systems has been working perfectly since I replaced the fans.